# Wed Element Sorting in Ascending Order using Array single unit and double digit unit

Tags: java, arrays, selenium-webdriver

I am able to sort with this below code in ascending order but due to the single unit and double digit unit (means 9, 19,5,12) it doesn't order sort accordingly

This is dynamic table in which I have to validate ascending and Descending order.

```
        String temp = null;
    List<WebElement> editicons1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//mat-table//mat-row/mat-cell[2]"));
    String strArray[] = new String[editicons1.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < editicons1.size(); i++) {
        editicons1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//mat-table//mat-row/mat-cell[2]"));
        Reporter.log(AddRule + " Cloumn as per display order " + editicons1.get(i).getText());
        Add_Log.info(AddRule + " Cloumn as per display order " + editicons1.get(i).getText());
        // System.out.println(editicons1.get(i).getText());
        strArray[i] = editicons1.get(i).getText();
    }
    // Sort the Array by Swapping the Elements
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < strArray.length; j++) {
            if (strArray[i].compareTo(strArray[j]) < 0) {
                temp = strArray[i];
                strArray[i] = strArray[j];
                strArray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    // Printing the Values after sorting in ascending order
    System.out.println("##################Sorted values in the Array and compare order####################");
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
         System.out.println(strArray[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        if (strArray[i].contentEquals(editicons1.get(i).getText())) {
            // if (strArray[i].compareTo(editicons1.get(i).getText()) != 0) {
            Reporter.log(AddRule + strArray[i] + " Cloumn is display in  Ascending order");
            Add_Log.info(AddRule + strArray[i] + " Cloumn is display in  Ascending order");
        } else {
            Reporter.log(AddRule + " Cloumn is not in order");
            Add_Log.info(AddRule + " Cloumn is not in order");
            Assert.fail();
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT

```
No. Cloumn as per display order 5
No. Cloumn as per display order 7
No. Cloumn as per display order 8
No. Cloumn as per display order 10
No. Cloumn as per display order 11
No. Cloumn as per display order 12
No. Cloumn as per display order 19
No. Cloumn as per display order 22
No. Cloumn as per display order 92
No. Cloumn as per display order 96
No. Cloumn as per display order 98
No. Cloumn as per display order 99
##################Sorted values in the Array and compare order####################
99
98
96
92
8
7
5
22
19
12
11
10
No. Cloumn is not in order
```

How can I correct sorting order with single and double unit number.

Comment: You are sorting based on strings not numbers. If you want to sort by numerical value you will need to convert the strings to numbers first.

Comment: @JeffC how can I achieve that ?

Comment: int i = Integer.parseInt(sortedList);   where should I place ? Is is correct?  I get this error "The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<String>)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison is made at this line

```
if (strArray[i].compareTo(strArray[j]) > 0) {
 ...
```

inorder to change the sort order from ascending to descending you only need to change `>` to `<`

**EDIT**

As commented by others, inorder to sort by numerical value you will need to convert the strings to numbers. You can do so by changing the above to:

```
if (Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]), Integer.parseInt(strArray[j])) > 0){
...
```

Comment: Thanks but now I have problem with single and double unit number

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string array to integer array and you can apply any algorithm to sort the array.

```
int arr []= new int[strArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i]>arr[j]) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you want to sort the string array put it there. There is nothing special to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the list in the accending order, the quickest way to reverse the list,  See here: [Reverse array list](http://www.java67.com/2016/10/3-ways-to-reverse-array-in-java-coding-interview-question.html)

For sorting in descending order, the string values need to be converted to integer type (assume the integer type can hold the value span), then you can just do:

```
    // convert the array to list
    List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(strArray);

    // sort the list in descending order 
    Collections.sort(strList, (a, b) -> Integer.parseInt(a) > Integer.parseInt(b) ? -1 : 1);
```